# Regex that detects only hyphen start with space

Tags: regex

I need a regex for hypens that start with whitespace like  `-`, not `-`:

```
- hello, - this is what I want!
```

... should match:

```
- this is what I want!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention you lang, but this will work in almost languages:

```
/\s-.*?($|,)/
```

Comment: Thank you Alijvhr. I'm just trying to test on regexr.com.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one-

```js
console.log(/^(?=.* -)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/.test(' -hello')); // true
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the content of the sentence is not fixed.